# Multiple entrance points in project

Tags: c++, builds, tests

My question is related to C++ but it comes from Java actually.

When I was programming Java I had multiple classes, which were derived from a base "Test" class. Their purpose was to test things - run tests (unit tests/not unit tests).

In order to run a test, I had a `public static void main` in every class. So the matter of running such a test was to click run in *Eclipse/Netbeans*, whatever good IDE.

I know this question maybe IDE dependent, it actually boils down to a makefiles, but is it possible to maintain a similar structure in C++ IDEs?

Actually my question is: **how do you deal with tests?**

Do you put a huge main method with some switch/enum based statements to run the tests or make different build configurations for each test, or have different solution to this?

I know this question won't get a straightforward answer, but I'm curious how to deal with it so I can choose something for myself.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using a unit testing framework that does these things for you in a clean way?

Comment: Yes, because It's impossible to unit test OpenGL shaders and nested 3d transforms other than visually.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel:  Sometimes it's handy to have a less-formal test jig for use during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't do this in C or C++ as easily as you can in Java."

Java lets you get away with having a `main()` method in every class because each class is its own namespace and can, in theory, be completely self-contained.  When you invoke the JVM on a class, you're telling it which namespace contains the `main()` you want it to run.  So, for example, `java Foo` really means "run `Foo.main()`."

Languages that compile to native objects don't work that way.  Most systems have a bit of code that gets linked into executables and is responsible for doing a bit of pre-flight prep, calling `main()` and passing the `int` that it returns back to the operating system as an exit code.  (On many Unixy systems, that code is in a file called `crt0.o`, or "C runtime zero.")  There's no simple way to pass in an alternate `main()` function at runtime because the linker has to sew all of that up beforehand.

If you want to achieve something similar in C or C++, you have a couple of choices:

One way is to use the preprocessor to subvert the usual things `main()` does and call a method directly if a symbol is defined:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    static void test() { // Your Test Here }
};

int main() {
#ifdef TEST_CLASS
  TEST_CLASS ## ::test();
#else
  // Do whatever main() usually does
#endif
}
```

Then, to make this work, you'd have to have your IDE define `TEST_CLASS` to the name of the class whose test you'd like to run, recompile and run.

The other way is to compile all of your objects into a shared library and add exported-to-C symbols to run your tests.  Then you'd need a small program that uses the dynamic loader to fish out the symbol for the test you want to run and call it.  How you'd do this is very system-dependent and has no basis in a standard, so I'm not going to recommend it or elaborate on how it's done.

Comment: The thing you are talking about - I've actually done. Created defines separate for each test I wanted to perform. I've found that this is close to how test frameworks do this.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an accepted answer, but I think the answer is incomplete (especially since it said *you can't* define multiple application entry points as easily as java).

To implement multiple entry points into the same code/module with C++, you do the following:

- create a new cpp file for each entry point (i.e. main-app.cpp, io-tests.cpp, db-tests.cpp, network-tests.cpp, etc).
- each file should define it's own main function.
- each file should have a separate binary target in your build system (make file?).
- build and run targets as needed.

Basically it's as easy as writing multiple `main` functions, each in their own file.

This solution works best if your main() function (in the example above, the one defined in "main-app.cpp") is as thin as possible.

A good implementation would look similar to this:

main-app.cpp:

```
#include <application.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    application app(std::cin, std::cout); // run application with std i/o
    return app.run();
}
```

db-tests.cpp:

```
#include <database.hpp>    // tested class
#include <unit-tests.hpp>  // unit testing fw

int main(int, char**) {
    database_test_suite suite;
    return suite.run();
}
```

You would have no target that compiles both of these files together (so you would not have any linker error with multiple definitions for main).